# MVC3 & Rhino Mocks starter example

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rhino-mocks

I started using MVC3 and Rhino mocks. Can someone provide me an example to write tests for

1. Checking for invalid data.
2. Handle scenarios you receive Null objects.
3. How to handle unique constraint errors.

using Rhino Mocks(any other tests if necessary).

Comment: on 3 how are you referring to this - Exceptions can be handled with attributes provided by your unit testing framework, are you looking for something different?

Comment: I din't start any coding yet. Wanted to go through an example and start working. I am not looking for anything different.

Comment: Didn't Darin answer this on how you check for invalid data on your past post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235455/how-to-mock-a-model-in-mvc3-when-using-rhino-mocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the mvcContrib TestHelper.
You can find examples and Documentation [here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper&referringTitle=Documentation)
You can download it from [nuget](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcContrib.Mvc3.TestHelper-ci) or from [CodePlex](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases)